# Change the table tr border color

Tags: html, css

I had a table as:

```
<table border="0" class="box">
    <tr height="25%" class="tableHead">
        <td align="center">Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25%">
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25%">
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25%">
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css as:

```
.box{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border:5px solid #427BD6;
    border-radius:8px;
}

.tableHead{
    background:#427BD6;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #427BD6;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I want to remove the white space in between title tr and the table border or change its color.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i had tried border-collapse:collapse but it hides border radius

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I've edited it out of my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your .box class: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSdbN/1/)

```
.box { 
    border-spacing:0;
}
```

Failing that, change your table tag to: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSdbN/)

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="box">
```

Comment: thanks it worked!,one more clarification is it possible to give a table border in double color as in [Link](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart)

Answer (score 0):

Add cellspacing="0" in your table. That will work!